# Ajax Scrip not displaying any result from the php file when the Dropdown is populated from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I created a dropdown list from MySql and I would like to use Ajax to pass the selection to another dropdown list. Surprisingly, when in the php file I initialise the php  I don't get any result, and if I do not initialise it I receive the exact content of the php file. The script works when I populate the dropdown list hardcoding the options, but not when I populate them from php.

In my main php file I have:

```
  </div>  

  <p>Company <span>*</span></p>
  <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></span>
  <select name="company" id="company">
    echo '<option value=""></option>;'

        <?php

        $query="SELECT `name` FROM `companies` ORDER BY `name`ASC";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Query to get data from sector table failed: ".mysql_error());


        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $company_id=$row["company_id"];


        $company_name=$row["name"];
        echo "<option value=\"$company_id\">
         $company_name
         </option>";
        }

        ?>

    </select>

  </div> 
 </div>  
<div id="show">
```

The Ajax Script goes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#company").change(function(){ 
  var company = $(this).val(); 
  var dataString = "company="+company; 

  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "get-data.php", 
    data: dataString, 
    success: function(result){
    $("#show").html(result); 
    }
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Finally My get-data.php looks like:

```
<?php
$output = ($_POST['company']);
echo $output;
?>
```

Everything works fine if I use manual options for the dropdown menu, but when I use this code to populate the dropdown list, the Ajax scrips stops working

```
   <?php

    $query="SELECT `name` FROM `companies` ORDER BY `name`ASC";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Query to get data from sector table failed: ".mysql_error());


    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $company_id=$row["company_id"];


    $company_name=$row["name"];
    echo "<option value=\"$company_id\">
     $company_name
     </option>";
    }

    ?>
```

Can you please help I am spending days and nights on this.

Regards
Tommaso

Comment: Can you add the following three statements to get-data.php and report if you have anything? ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Also there's a small problem on the 5th line of your html code. echo '<option value=""></option>;' is not wrapped in the PHP tags. Altough it will most likely not solve your issue as I literally copied and pasted all your code and it worked on my end.

Comment: What is the point of get-data.php if all it does is return back what was passed in? You could handle that within the JS code without any PHP.

Comment: @Lou I added the code you suggested, but i receive no error on the webpage. If I open the console on the get-data.php page I see the following: 

<script type="text/javascript">( function(){ window.SIG_EXT = {}; } )()</script> =$0

Comment: @Lou does it really work on your end, does it mean I have some column or data wrong?

Comment: @Andrew, I tried with JS script before but I couldn't find a solution, because the dropdown is populated by the backend

Comment: @Lou I edited the post because I found that the php scripts breaks the code, any suggestion?